# How to export sorted data into Excel sheet from Crystal Report?

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

I am trying to export a report from Crystal Reports 9 to an Excel Sheet. The data in Excel sheet isn't sorting in the right order. How to export sorted data into Excel sheet from Crystal Report?

Answer (score 0):

sort data before  crystalReport.SetDataSource(); 
in export data style is the same as displayed in view

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the Following Code it doesn't working, Please Can you send right code 

DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["VISTA_Report"];
DataView dv=ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort="vehNo ASC";
cr.SetDataSource(dv);